# When exactly is NoClassDefFoundError thrown?

Tags: java, dependencies, runtime, classpath

How do runtime dependencies in Java work exactly. For example, is code like this possible if `Impl1` or `Impl2` are not in the classpath at runtime:

```
Thinger t;
if (classIsAvailable(Impl1.class)) t = new Impl1();
else t = new Impl2();
t.doThing();
```

Or if there is no common interface:

```
if (classIsAvailable(Impl1.class)) Impl1.doThingThisWay();
else Impl2.doThingTheOtherWay();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example would fail with a [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) when your class is loaded with either `Impl1` or `Impl2` not in the classpath, so none of the code would execute in that case.

Comment: Well I suppose a reasonable extension of the question would be *When are classes loaded?*. If I had e.g. an `Impl1Wrapper` which refers to `Impl1`, and an equivalent for `Impl2`, could an `ImplChooser` class which refers to both wrappers without reflection be loaded if either `ImplX` is not on the classpath (but both wrappers are)?

Comment: @Bart: I think that depends on how exactly these classes are implemented. If the missing classes are not part of any method signature or field definition in the wrappers (i.e. they appear only in method bodies) I believe it would work. But the easiest way to be certain is to try it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it exactly like this, because in order to evaluate `Impl1.class`, said class must be available (i.e. loaded). You can however try to load a specific class by its name

```
 Class aClass = classLoader.forName("Impl1");
```

If this does not fail (throw an Exception) you can create an instance of this class using `newInstance()`.

Of course, in order to be able to **use** your class, you have to make sure it implements an Interface, which **is** known at compile time. In this case you can cast your created object to that interface type and continue using it.

[This article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html) has some sample code.

Comment: What if the two implementations offer the same functionality but without a shared interface? Is reflection the only way to call them then?

Answer (score 2):

ClassNotFoundException is thrown when
an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

```
* The forName method in class Class.
* The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
* The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.
```

but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

You may also find http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17 useful.

HTH

Comment: I used the wrong exception name. I meant `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: @Bart NoClassDefFoundError occurs when u compile the code successfully and the running code could not find required classes at runtime due to missing libraries of class files.

Comment: That I know. The question was when exactly classes *become required* at runtime.